# Finding an element in B+ tree using Scheme

Tags: list, scheme, racket, b-tree, b-plus-tree

I need to traverse the B+ tree. If i hit a list i need to deal with it and recursively keep going till i get an element. Then i compare it to the number given. If the number is more than the greatest number in that list i can ignore that branch (list). Same for when it's less. I just need to traverse the tree and find the element. It should work no matter the tree given

This is what i did

```
(define ones (list '() 2 '() 4 '() 6 '() 7 '() 8 '()))
(define sixties (list '() 52 '() 54 '() 66 '() 67 '() 68 '()))
(define tens (list ones 10 '() 30 '() 50 sixties 70 '() 90 '()))
(define ninehundreds (list '() 930 '() 940 '() 960 '() 970 '() 988 '()))
(define tree (list tens 100 '() 300 '() 500 '() 700 '() 900 ninehundreds ))

(define (walk tree num)
   (if list? (car tree)
       (walk-list (car tree)))

  (if (not list? (car tree)))
       walk-list( cdr tree)
)

(define (walk-list lst)
  (if (list? (car lst)) (walk-list (car lst)))
  (if (not (list? (car lst))) (car lst))
)
(walk tree 0)
```

I have an issue with the two `if`s in both defined functions. Also i kept getting back `#t` at one point

edit: I believe I fixed my understanding with the syntax errors. But now I get this message on the `if` statement in `walk-list`

```
mcar: contract violation
  expected: mpair?
  given: ()
```

```
(define (walk tree num)
   (if (list? (car tree))
       (walk-list (car tree))
       (car tree))
)

(define (walk-list lst)
  (if  (list? (car lst))
    (walk-list (car lst))
    (car lst))
)
```

Comment: You're ignoring the result of the first conditional. The syntax is `(if condition true-clause false-clause)`.

Comment: `(if (not list? (car tree)))` should be giving a syntax error because `if` needs at least two arguments in Scheme and exactly three in Racket. That only has one. (And `not` should have one argument, not two)

Comment: Start with much smaller test cases. First do the smallest possible tree, then add one complication at a time. (And you probably shouldn't be ignoring the `cdr`.)

Comment: These also helped me get closer to my answer!

Answer (score 1):

> I need to traverse the b+ tree. If i hit a list i need to deal with it and
> recursively keep going till i get an element. Then i compare it to the
> number given. If the number is more than the greatest number in that list i
> can ignore that branch(list). Same for its less. I just need to traverse the
> tree and find the element. It should work no matter the tree given

```
(define ones (list '() 2 '() 4 '() 6 '() 7 '() 8 '()))
(define sixties (list '() 52 '() 54 '() 66 '() 67 '() 68 '()))
(define tens (list ones 10 '() 30 '() 50 sixties 70 '() 90 '()))
(define ninehundreds (list '() 930 '() 940 '() 960 '() 970 '() 988 '()))
(define tree (list tens 100 '() 300 '() 500 '() 700 '() 900 ninehundreds ))
```

##### How to get started: write a ***data definition*** with some ***simple examples***:

```
; a Tree is one of:
;  (1) '(), or
;  (2) a List ('() KNum <'() KNum> ... '()), or
;  (3) a List (NonEmptyTree INum <Tree INum> ... Tree)
; (where "<a b> ..." means two list elements a b occur zero or more times)
; KNums and INums are Numbers; the KNums are sorted, and each INum is > all KNums preceding it.
;
; examples of Trees:
;   (1): '()
;   (2): (list '() 1 '())
;   (2): (list '() 1 '() 2 '())
;   (3): (list (list '() 1 '()) 10 '())
;   (3): (list (list (list '() 1 '()) 10 '()) 10 '())
;   (3): (list (list '() 1 '()) 10 (list '() 10 '()) 20 (list '() 21 '()))
```

##### Choose a good name for a function, write a first ***check-expect*** and ***function stub***, with ***signature*** and ***purpose***:

(`check-expect` is available in Racket's [Student Languages](https://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/index.html);
data definition/stub/signature/purpose are part of a [Systematic Program Design](https://htdp.org/2023-3-6/Book/part_preface.html#%28part._sec%7E3asystematic-design%29)
process, for which there are [Design Recipes](https://legacy.cs.indiana.edu/classes/c211/2021f-c211-000.png))

```
(check-expect (tree-search '() 1)  #f )

(define (tree-search tree num) ;; Tree KNum -> List or #f
  ;; produce first list within |tree| with first element |num|, or #f if not found
  #f)
```

##### Write `check-expect`s for Tree case (1) and use them to write the code.

```
(check-expect (tree-search-1 '() 1)  #f )
(check-error  (tree-search-1 (list '() 1 '()) 1) )  ;; (tree must be ())

(define (tree-search-1 tree num) ;; Tree(1) KNum -> List or #f
  ;; produce first list within |tree| with first element |num|, or #f if not found
  (cond
    [(null? tree) #f ]  ;; tree is ()
    [else (error) ]))
```

##### Now do the same for Tree case (2): *note that each `check-` shows how to write the `cond` clause.*

```
(check-expect (tree-search-2 '() 1)                     #f )
(check-error  (tree-search-2 (list 'x) 1) )
(check-expect (tree-search-2 (list '() 1 '())       1)  (list 1 '()) )
(check-expect (tree-search-2 (list '() 2 '())       1)  #f )
(check-expect (tree-search-2 (list '() 1 '())       2)  #f )
(check-expect (tree-search-2 (list '() 1 '() 2 '()) 2)  (list 2 '()) )

(define (tree-search-2 tree num) ;; Tree(1|2) KNum -> List or #f
  ;; produce first list within |tree| with first element |num|, or #f if not found
  ;; |tree| is () or (() KNum <() KNum> ... ())
  (cond
    [(null? tree) #f ]                        ;; tree is ()
    [(not (null? (car tree))) (error) ]       ;; tree is (x ...)
    [(= (cadr tree) num) (cdr tree) ]         ;; tree is (() num ...)
    [(> (cadr tree) num) #f ]                 ;; tree is (() >num ...)
    [(null? (cdddr tree)) #f ]                ;; end of list: not found
    [else (tree-search-2 (cddr tree) num) ])) ;; search (<() KNum> ... )
```

##### Now one can continue to write more `check-expect`s and write the full `tree-search` for all 3 Tree cases.

It can call `tree-search-2`, and it may also be convenient for it to call a "`tree-search-rest`" function
to handle the "<Tree INum> ... Tree" part of Tree(3).

.
.
.

##### Finally, a few tests using the example tree from the question:

```
(check-expect (tree-search tree 8)    (list 8 '()) )
(check-expect (tree-search tree 67)   (list 67 '() 68 '()) )
(check-expect (tree-search tree 988)  (list 988 '()) )
(check-expect (tree-search tree 5)    #f )
(check-expect (tree-search tree 10)   #f )
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This definitely helped me Understand scheme a bit more

Answer (score 0):

Try it at the REPL:

```
> (list? '())
#t
```

whereas

```
> (pair? '())
#f
```

You can't call `car` on `'()`. This will cause the error you're shown.